# How can I reproduce the multithreading error mentioned in the code specification?(TSM03-J. Do not publish partially initialized objects)

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-safety

I am using Google Translate to read "SEI CERT Oracle Coding Standard for Java".

One of the suggestions is
[TSM03-J. Do not publish partially initialized objects](https://wiki.sei.cmu.edu/confluence/display/java/TSM03-J.+Do+not+publish+partially+initialized+objects),
It gives the code that will cause "publish partially initialized objects"

I want to reproduce the error mentioned in the article, but I failed. Can someone give me example code?

Do not confuse with the following scenario, although it can also get partially initialized objects.
[TSM01-J. Do not let the this reference escape during object construction](https://wiki.sei.cmu.edu/confluence/display/java/TSM01-J.+Do+not+let+the+this+reference+escape+during+object+construction)

```java
class Foo {
  private Helper helper;

  public Helper getHelper() {
    return helper;
  }

  public void initialize() {
    helper = new Helper(42);
  }
}

public class Helper {
  private int n;

  public Helper(int n) {
    this.n = n;
  }
  // ...
}
```

Then there is an explanation on that page

> If a thread were to access helper using the getHelper() method before the initialize() method executed, the thread would observe an uninitialized helper field. Later, if one thread calls initialize() and another calls getHelper(), the second thread could observe one of the following:
>
> - The helper reference as null
> - A fully initialized Helper object with the n field set to 42
> - A partially initialized Helper object with an uninitialized n, which contains the default value 0

For testing purposes, I added the following code to "Helper"

```java
    public int getN() {
        return n;
    }
```

Following is the test code, I thought the test code would output "publish partially initialized objects", but nothing happened.

```java
public class Program {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        boolean getZero = false;
        while (!getZero) {

            Foo foo = new Foo();
            new Thread(foo::initialize).start();

            while (true) {
                Helper helper;
                if ((helper = foo.getHelper()) != null) {
                    if (helper.getN() == 0) {
                        getZero = true;
                        System.out.println("publish partially initialized objects");
                    }
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

How can I reproduce the multithreading error mentioned in the code specification?

Answer (score 0):

From the same page,

> In particular, the JMM permits compilers to allocate memory for the new Helper object and to assign a reference to that memory to the helper field before initializing the new Helper object. In other words, the compiler can reorder the write to the helper instance field and the write that initializes the Helper object (that is, this.n = n) so that the former occurs first. ***This can expose a race window during which other threads can observe a partially initialized Helper object instance.***

To observe partially initialized object here, your code needs to hit this race window when reading foo.getHelper().getN(). You could run the it millions of times and still not have this happen. Like most multithreading related bugs, its not easy to replicate.